# Intel Graphics Driver and Control Panel keeps reinstalling itself

Tags: windows-10, drivers, intel-graphics

It is on an old Lenovo laptop. Win 10 64 bit.

It always had problems with random BSOD with error in dxgmm2.sys, as millions of cases around the world. Following suggestions, I tried to uninstall graphics drivers and it is impossible, worse than a virus..........

In Windows Update I have selected NOT to install other drivers but it continues to reinstall, even if I see it in the Optional Updates with a unchecked check box, that I stay far way.

After that I discovered this driver reinstalls itself at boot even with Windows Update in pause state.

I have removed Graphic Control Panel and Intel Graphics Driver BOTH from the Old Control Panel -> Programs and Features AND from the Win 10 Settings -> Apps. No matter what, this thing reappears at next reboot.

I have also deleted Intel Graphics Driver from Device Manager, so Display Adapter reverts to Microsoft Basic Driver, but at next reboot, it reappears and reinstall itself.

If I log quickly it is not there, but the screen blanks for a bit after some seconds and it reappears. But if I wait without logging, I log with this thing already in. So it is not at Logon, but at pure boot phase.

I have checked the various registry keys for automatic startup, nothing is there.

I have also stopped all  Lenovo services, in case Intel did some hidden pact with them to reinstall it anyway, but it didn't work.

Please tell me what shound I do to get rid permanently of Intel Graphics Driver and its Control Panel, forever and without inserting itself with or without Windows Update.

Big thanks for any suggestion.

Things I did NOT do:

1 Remove all other Intel stuff for laptops: bus, cpu drivers, and so on, maybe they install graphic driver too? Should I remove them?

2 In Windows/System32 there are a lot of "igx..." files that seem related to this. I have yet to dare to delete them no matter what, but it seems I have nothing to lose at this point. suggestions?

3 Obviously, reformat and reinstall. That the ultimate solution but I hope avoid. Also, there is not guarantee Windows does not install 3rd party drivers at its own install and after finishing it asks the user what to do, so raising the problem again.

Comment: This really feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please ask us about the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than how to implement your assumed solution.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't see anything justifying your feeling, My primary language is not English but it should be clear I want to get rid of Intel Graphics Driver from my system. This is my problem now.

Comment: Getting rid of the Intel driver is the 'Y' of your problem. You need to ask us about the 'X'.

Comment: @Tetsujin Getting rid of Intel driver is a perfectly valid technical question for this community, or am I wrong? I don't think I "need" to tell anything else regardless of any preceding circumstances. If you have questions, I try to clarify, otherwise, thx anywway.

Comment: OK, what GPU chip is it?

Comment: @Tetsujin I have this: "Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600". Task Manager, Powershell, DXDiag and Device Manager don't give further details.

Comment: That's one of the chipsets dropped by Intel at Win10. They made one transitional driver for it in 2015 & then what I call the 'late apology' driver in 2021 - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/products/81496/graphics/intel-hd-graphics-family/intel-hd-graphics-4600.html - basically, support for it ended with Win 8.1.

Comment: You might also look in Windows Optional updates . My 7 year old ThinkPad just had an Intel HID update that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Please tell me what should I do to get rid permanently of Intel Graphics Driver and its Control Panel, forever and without inserting itself with or without Windows Update.*

You probably cannot.

Intel makes extensive use of the Microsoft Update Catalog and will continue to update the driver.

I have Lenovo Graphics on a Lenovo X230 (10 year old), Thinkpad X1 7 years old and Thinkpad X1 2 years old.

I do not get BSOD errors on these machines but I have had graphics driver errors occasionally on the 7 year old Thinkpad.

**(1) The first solution to the driver error is as follows:**

> Ensure Windows is fully up to date including optional updates.
>
> Download and install Lenovo Software Updater.
>
> Uninstall the Graphics Driver and added Intel Graphics control panel
> software (Programs and Features and Device Driver).
>
> Restart, install / update the Graphics driver and use Software Updater
> to update all drivers.

**(2)** The above normally works for me across several machines. If not for you, then it may be time to back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thx very much for the answer. I have done all that except Lenovo sw udater, the Graphics Driver 4600 I have is the last one for that laptop. Update Drivers and Windows Update does not show any newer versions. The Intel site does not offer anything else. The BSOD problem arose when I updated Windows.... it is fresh and error free (DISM and SFC 100% ok).

Comment: "You probably cannot." I forgot, I would liked upvote for this but I am too new.  The truth everyone knows but no one say loud. I will find time to reformat, or throw away the laptop.

Comment: You can Accept the answer if you wish to (all members can accept answers)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, it seems after dozen hours the system is stable.

The main purpose was eliminate from the system the Intel Graphics Driver because since a big Win Update the system was unstable (BSODs for the infamous dxgmms2.sys).

Obviously, nothing is so simple since I discovered  that often the Windows Basic Display Driver (or something) does not detect the external monitor at cold boot.

I found in Optional Updates after several reboots something like "Intel Graphics Driver WMI". I installed it without much thinking, being determined to reformat and reinstall.

I do not know why it appeared at this point, I am sure I never saw it in Optional Updates.

It seems close to John's suggestion (hence the accepted answer).

That optional update solved the problem.

Until now.

(but actually, I am bothered by the difficulty they create to remove some driver from my own machine. This I will continue to research)